# Massless Pulley having friction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram, string

I want to ask whether it is (theoretically) possible that there is a pulley with no mass but has friction in it....Why or Why not ? Also will the tension on both sides of it be the same or different (since it has friction)...??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mass less pulley can have friction; between the pulley and the cord, and also at the axle on which rotates. If it has both, and is rotating, then the tension will be different on the two sides.